# How did I get the dnd-5e tag badge when I'm ignoring all the dnd tags I can find?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

Just what it says on the tin -- I just received the "dnd-5e" tag badge, but I haven't answered a "dnd-5e" question in a couple months, because I started ignoring them to curtail temptation to answer when I don't have resources at work to make *good* answers.

In the past, when I've gotten tag badges (here and on other SE sites) they were always relevant to either recent answers or recent vote activity on slightly older answers.  How does this happen in my situation?

Comment: You have 59 answers for a score of 663. You've had the badge for a while now, so your issue is the same as the linked question.

Comment: Yep, you're right, that's probably it.  Does that mean this question should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, it's the same problem (which just now received a resolution from our SE overlords).